# Koren siddurim/machzorim for minyan

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, minyan

Does anyone know if there is someplace where a small start-up minyan can get schul sefarim,* preferably the Koren Sacks editions? We're putting together a yomim-noraim set-up and we are all fans of the Koren, at least as far as translated editions go.

---

*Siddurim, Chumashim, Machzorim, et c.

Comment: do you mean at bulk/discounted prices or a place that has extra to donate?

Comment: @Danno, Either works, although I doubt the latter would apply to the machzorim, seeing how new they are.

Comment: http://www.judaism.com/search.asp?keyword=Koren+Siddur&nt=DH&itemtype= If you email them with the full list of what you need and the amounts, you can probably get a volume discount.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy directly from [Koren](http://www.korenpub.com/EN/index.php) and they are currently 30% off through December 2, 2014